# SpringBoot: Entity json serialisation with inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson

I have a below class structure

```java
@Entity
public class Car {
     @Column
     private String make; 
     @Column
     private String model; 

     @Column
     private TransmissionType transmissionType; // Manual/Automatic

     @Column
     @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "transmissionType")
     private Transmission transmission;        // <--- This should be stored as JSON
                                               //      by using the `transmissionType` field
}

@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AutomaticTransmission.class, name = "Automatic"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ManualTransmission.class, name = "Manual")
})
public abstract class Transmission {
}

public class AutomaticTransmission {
     public Technology technology; // DCT/CVT/AMT
}

public class ManualTransmission {
     public int numGears; 
}
```

When the data is being stored in table, it should be stored as

```
| make   | model   | transmission_type | transmission           |
_________________________________________________________________
| Toyota | Iris    | Automatic         | {"technology": "DCT"}  | 
| Merc   | Class C | Manual            | {"numGears": 5}        |
```

I tried using `JsonStringType` from `vladmihalcea`s hibernate by changing code as below

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Car {
     ... 
     @Column
     @Type(type = "json")
     private Transmission transmission;
}
```

In this case, the serialization works properly but while reading the data.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xxx.Transmission` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)""{\"numGears\":30}""; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar:2.11.3]
```

Even though I have specified `JsonTypeInfo`. I am open with changing approach as long as the JSON stored in database doesn't store type information. I want it to be inferred from `transmissionType`.

Comment: The exception message explicitly lists SystemSettingsEntity as missing a compatible constructor. This is not one of the classes in your post.

Comment: @Deadron thanks for noticing this. I had translated the problem to more generic and open problem. Have corrected the error message.

Comment: was any solution found?